# Find all/particular SSID

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi, ssid

I'm new to iOS development and have searched this site but some of the info dates back a few years. Am I right in thinking that it's not possible to get a list of all SSID's in range without using private API's? Is there an alternative of having my app receive a notification of sorts if a particular SSID is detected?

thank you

Comment: What have you found out so far? Have you check the documentation on http://developer.apple.com ??

Comment: I found out that it's not possible without private API's but those were answers from a couple of years back (as mentioned in my post). I want to confirm that it's still the case. I have looked at the documentation but couldn't find anything - but I'm new to iOS so may be looking in the wrong place.